# j, jco, jc or jo don't exist after installing autojump on Mac OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I installed autojump on my Mac OSX Yosemite with brew with

```
brew install autojump
```

Now, I can't use it because when I try to use it:

```
jc asfg
-bash: jc: command not found

jo asfg
-bash: jo: command not found

j asdj
-bash: j: command not found
```

none of them exist. Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you haven't done so already, you may want to follow the instructions printed on my most recent install:

```
Add the following line to your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc file (and remember
to source the file to update your current session):
  [[ -s $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh ]] && . $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh
```

For example, if you added the line to .bash_profile, you can source it as follows:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Or, just spin up a new command shell and the variables should have taken effect.

If you don't have any success with that, it's time to seriously trouble-shoot.

If you installed correctly, you should have a file named autojump.sh under your brew directory (which you can see using `brew --prefix`). If that file's there, you should be able to perform the following command, which should temporarily allow use of autojump commands in that particular shell:

```
. $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh
```

If you are successful with the autojump commands, it's a matter of modifying your .bashrc or .zshrc file as stated at the top of this answer.

If autojump commands are still nowhere in sight, I'd try a "brew uninstall autojump" followed by a "brew install autojump". Oh, and be sure to follow precisely the instructions in the "Caveats" section following the successful install.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "source the file"?

Comment: For example, if you added the line to .bash_profile, you can source it as follows:  

. ~/.bash_profile

Comment: still same problem:  `. ~/.bash_profile
jc
-bash: jc: command not found
 j
-bash: j: command not found`

Comment: Did you update the .bashrc?  It should also work if you just cut and paste the last line (starting with [[ ) and then try the commands

Comment: Yes I executed the line of code with no output but still same problem :(

Comment: Ok let's see.  If you installed correctly, you should have a file named autojump.sh under your brew directory (which you can see using `brew --prefix`).  If that file's there, you should be able to perform the following command: `. $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh`    If that gives any errors (or doesn't fix the issue), I'd try a "brew uninstall autojump" followed by a "brew install autojump".  Oh, and be sure to follow precisely the instructions in the "Caveats" section following the successful install.

Comment: nice, I had to uninstall it and install it back, don't know exactly what happened, but thank you for your support!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83461/discussion-between-rholmes-and-saul-ortega).

Answer (score 7):

Assumed that you use `zsh` shell, you have to manually add the plugin link.
See the instructions blew:

1. in your terminal, open and edit `.zshrc` file by **nano** or **vim**:

   `$ nano ~/.zshrc` or `$ vim ~/.zshrc`
2. add `plugins=(autojump)` in the `.zshrc` file
   [image]
3. re-open your terminal